# Implementing turn by turn navigation in Android using Mapbox SDK

Tags: android, maps, mapbox, directions, google-directions-api

I am trying to implement turn by turn feature into my app using Mapbox Android SDK. Although Mapbox has [Drive](https://www.mapbox.com/drive/) listed as their product I am not able to find any documentation/examples on how to use it (maybe their are still working on it).

Anyways, I think I need to built it by myself. Getting direction coordinates and drawing poly-lines is all fine. I am stuck here - in the response of the direction api of the Mapbox we have `steps` json object which contains turn by turn instructions. Lets say there are 3 points under `steps` object say A,B,C where

- A = lat1, lng1 (origin)
- B = lat2, lng2
- C = lat3, lng3 (destination)

Now, I would like to know how can we identify if we have reached point B so that we can show user the next instruction. I am assuming we just can't do

```
lat1 == lat2 && lng1 == lng2
```

Is there any way we can identify when the user reaches a point on the map. I am thinking of adding `Geofence` on the next point in the list there by getting notified when user enters the `Geofence` and can update the instruction to the next point in the list and add a Geofence to it too, but I am not sure if its the right approach. Is there any other way we can achieve this ??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into our [`RouteUtils`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/libjava/lib/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/navigation/v5/RouteUtils.java). It includes the basic building blocks of what it's needed for navigation (we're on working on it!). Under the hood, we're using a port of Turf to Java to carry out all the GIS computations.

In your case, you could for example use something like `getSnapToRoute()` to get the closer point on the step to the user location to compute how far you're from the next turn.

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Okay wat will getSnapToRoute() return when we cross a point. The return value of the method is Position. Will it return null ?? Just trying to understand.

Comment: You should always get a `Position` returned from that method.